# How to count the search result using php

Tags: php, mysql

i have function to display the searched data with pagination but i want to count the total number of result available when search ,i have many search criteria so here i added `count(*) as total` to search query but its not work can any one guide me how to count and display here is my whole php code with pagination thanks.

```
<?php


  $tbl_name="contact";       //your table name
    $adjacents = 7;

    $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages['num'];

    $targetpage = "filterdata.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
    $limit = 10;    
    //how many items to show per page

    $page = $_GET['page'];
    if($page) 
        $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
    else
        $start = 0;                           //if no page var is given, set start to 0

    /* Get data. */
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) as total, DISTINCT contact.`id` , contact.`contactgroup` , contact.`media` ,contact.`media2` , contact.`email1` , contact.`nationality` , contact.`country3` , contact.`twon` , contact.`area` , contact.`gender` , contact.`married` , contact.`children` , contact.`driverslicense` 
            FROM $tbl_name ";
    if ($language !="" && $language !="Empty" )
    {
        $language_exp = explode(',', $language);
        $sql .= " INNER JOIN contactlanguage ON contact.id = contactlanguage.contactid
        INNER JOIN language ON contactlanguage.languageid = language.id where isdeleted = 0 AND language.language in ('".implode("', '", $language_exp)."') "; 
    }
    else
    {
        $sql .= " where isdeleted = 0";
    }
    if ($contactgroup !="" && $contactgroup !="Empty" )
    {
        $contactgroup_exp = explode(',', $contactgroup);
        $sql .= " AND contactgroup in ('".implode("', '", $contactgroup_exp)."')";
    }

    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media = '".$media."'";     
    }

    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "email" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media2 = '".$media."'";     
    }
    if ($media !="" && $media !="Empty" && $media == "sms,email" )
    {
        $sql.=" and media = 'sms' and media2 = 'email' ";     
    }
    if ($nationality !="" && $nationality !="Empty" )
    {
        $nationality_exp = explode(',', $nationality);
        $sql .= " AND nationality in ('".implode("', '", $nationality_exp)."')";  
    }
    if ($country !="" && $country !="Empty" )
    {
        $country_exp = explode(',', $country);
        $sql .= " AND country1 in ('".implode("', '", $country_exp)."')";     
    }
    if ($twon !="" && $twon !="Empty" )
    {
        $city_exp = explode(',', $twon);
        $sql .= " AND twon in ('".implode("', '", $city_exp)."')";   
    }
    if ($area !="" && $area !="Empty" )
    {
        $area_exp = explode(',', $area);
        $sql .= " AND area in ('".implode("', '", $area_exp)."')";       
    }
    if ($gender !="" && $gender !="Empty" && $gender !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and gender = '".$gender."'";     
    }
    if ($gender =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`gender` = 'female' OR `gender` = 'male' OR `gender` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($married !="" && $married !="Empty" && $married !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and married = '".$married."'";     
    }
    if ($married =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`married` = 'yes' OR `married` = 'no' OR `married` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($children !="" && $children !="Empty" && $children !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and children = '".$children."'";     
    }
    if ($children =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`children` = 'yes' OR `children` = 'no' OR `children` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($driver !="" && $driver !="Empty" && $driver !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and driverslicense = '".$driver."'";     
    }
    if ($driver =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`driverslicense` = 'yes' OR `driverslicense` = 'no' OR `driverslicense` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($retype !="" && $retype !="Empty" && $retype !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and retype = '".$retype."'";     
    }
    if ($retype =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`retype` = 'apart' OR `retype` = 'house' OR `retype` = '') ";     
    }
    if ($restatus !="" && $restatus !="Empty" && $restatus !="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" and restatus = '".$restatus."'";     
    }
    if ($restatus =="all" )
    {
        $sql.=" AND (`restatus` = 'owner' OR `restatus` = 'renting' OR `restatus` = '') ";     
    }

    if ($reproject !="" && $reproject !="Empty" )
    {
        $reproject_exp = explode(',', $reproject);
        $sql .= " AND reproject1 in ('".implode("', '", $reproject_exp)."')";    
    }

    if ($education !="" && $education !="Empty" )
    {
        $education_exp = explode(',', $education);
        $sql .= " AND education in ('".implode("', '", $education_exp)."')";    
    }

    if ($jobrole !="" && $jobrole !="Empty" )
    {
        $jobrole_exp = explode(',', $jobrole);
        $sql .= " AND jobrole in ('".implode("', '", $jobrole_exp)."')";   
    }

    if ($jobsector !="" && $jobsector !="Empty" )
    {
        $jobsector_exp = explode(',', $jobsector);
        $sql .= " AND jobsector in ('".implode("', '", $jobsector_exp)."')";   
    }

    if ($dataperiod !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="EmptyEmpty" && $arraydataperiodcount !="" && $dataperiod !="EmptyEmpty")
    {
        $sql.=" and dataperiod BETWEEN $arraydataperiodcount[0] AND $arraydataperiodcount[1] ";     
    }

    if ($age !="" && $age !="Empty" )
    {
        $sql.=" and age BETWEEN $agebetween[0] AND $agebetween[1] "; 
    }

    $sql.="LIMIT $start, $limit";

    print $sql;

    $result1 = mysql_query($sql);

    /* Setup page vars for display. */
    if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                    //if no page var is given, default to 1.
    $prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
    $next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
    $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
    //print $lastpage; 
    $lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

    /* 
        Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
        We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
    */
    $pagination = "";
    if($lastpage > 1)
    {   
        $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
        //previous button
        if ($page > 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\"> previous</a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\"> previous</span>"; 

        //pages 
        if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))    //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
        {   
            for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
        elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2)) //enough pages to hide some
        {
            //close to beginning; only hide later pages
            if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))     
            {
                for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //in middle; hide some front and some back
            elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
                $pagination.= "...";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";       
            }
            //close to end; only hide early pages
            else
            {
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=1\">1</a>";
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=2\">2</a>";
                $pagination.= "...";
                for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
                {
                    if ($counter == $page)
                        $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                    else
                        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
                }
            }
        }

        //next button
        if ($page < $counter - 1) 
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">next </a>";
        else
            $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">next </span>";
        $pagination.= "</div>\n";     
    }


//echo $sql;
//print $sql;

while($rows=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '  <td class="edit contactgroup '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["contactgroup"].'</td>';

    if($media == "sms")
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
    }
    else if($media == "email")
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media2"].'</td>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo' <td class="edit media '.$rows["id"].'" >'.$rows["media"].'</td>';
    }   
         echo ' <td class="edit email '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["email1"].'</td>
                <td class="edit nationality '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["nationality"].'</td>   
                <td class="edit country '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["country3"].'</td>
                <td class="edit twon '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["twon"].'</td>    
    <td class="edit area '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["area"].'</td>            
      <td class="edit gender '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["gender"].'</td>                  
         <td class="edit married '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["married"].'</td>             
          <td class="edit children '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["children"].'</td> 
          <td class="edit driverlicense '.$rows["id"].'">'.$rows["driverslicense"].'</td>       

            </tr>';
}

?>

<?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

Comment: do some reading [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php)

Comment: can you tell me how to write the query

Comment: you should use PDO statements its much easier to work with and its also safe.

Comment: try `$row_number = mysql_num_rows(queryhere);`

Comment: it showing just 10 because i am using limit in the query

Comment: duplicate the query without the limit and you will get the total number of rows

Comment: You already have the full table count stored in `$total_pages`.  What's the problem?

Comment: Can you give us 1) some example input data and 2) what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mysql_num_rows();
```

It will give you the number of results from database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to count the rows that have been returned from your MySQL query.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo 'number of rows: ' . $count_rows;
```

Reference from PHP manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Note: mysql_query() is deprecated as of PHP 5.5. You should use mysqli_query()

Answer (score 0):

u can run the query two times, one with a limit and the second one without the limit as thinkkso said and then do

```
mysql_num_rows($result);
```

or u could try giving PHP count function a try and see if it works.. [im not sure if this works]

```
$rows = count($result);
```

Comment: You're right, the `count()` method won't work unless you have *all of the result rows* stored in `$rows`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return the full table quantity AND the paginated data in the same query, you can do something like:

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3
FROM main_table
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) AS table_qty FROM main_table) table_count
LIMIT 10;
```

This query will return the columns `column1, column2, column3, table_qty`.  This works by calculating the total table quantity as `table_qty`, then using a `CROSS JOIN` to append it to all result records.

---

**Edit:** You already have the total table record quantity in `$total_pages`, use that instead.

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages = $total_pages['num'];
```